# Почему компьютер перестает "видет" жесткий диск после создания логического диска из раздела?

Tags: windows, hdd, partition

Имеется система с 2 жесткими дисками. На каждом в отдельном логическом диске стоит своя система - windows xp и windows 8.1. Основная система восьмерка, а старушка для старой проги по витражам. После очередного слета восьмерки диск, на котором она была установлена перестал видеть компьютер. Проверял на другом компе, прекрасно видит, а вот на родной системе, увы. Удалил логический диск со сбойной системой, диск временами "появляется" на родном компьютере. Но если только попытаться создать из этого раздела логический диск, он сразу пропадает в прежней системе. Кроме того, система пытается сделать активные разделы на обеих жестких дисках.
Возможно, в результате сбоя появились сбойные секторы в разделе, где был логический диск с восьмеркой. Но стандартными средствами его, раздел не проверишь, большинство программ требуют указать название логического диска. ВОзможно, есть программы, которые могут сканировать на битые сектора жесткие диски напрямую.
Буду рад услышать объяснение такому поведению системы и советам по поиску программ для сканирования жесткого диска в целом.

Comment: А виртуальная машина чем не устроила? Или прога для витражей хочет прямой проброс видюхи?

Comment: Буду очень рад, если поделитесь ссылочкой как устанавливать прогу под виртуалку с возможностью вывода на плоттер. Кроме того, у программы есть USB-ключ, с которым она получает возможность экспортировать и посылать на печать.

Comment: Я в VirtualBox отлично пробрасываю Sentinel usb ключи. И когда надо именно Rufus'ом записать образ на флэшку - я из убунты в гостевую винду тоже отлично пробрасываю и тоже отлично всё пашет. Как плоттер к компу подключается?